# Scoring documents in Lucene 6.2.0

Tags: lucene

My query in **lucene 6.2.0** goes like:

```
query query = new PhraseQuery.Builder()
                        .add(new Term("country","russia"))
                        .setSlop(1)
                        .build();
```

Basically among all my documents which are:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("586b723b4b9a835db416fa26"), 
    "name" : "test", 
    "countries" : {
        "country" : [
            {
                "name" : "russia"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "USA china"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("586b73f24b9a835fefb10ca5"), 
    "name" : "nitika jain", 
    "countries" : {
        "country" : [
            {
                "name" : "russia and denmrk"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "USA china"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("586b744f4b9a835fefb10ca7"), 
    "name" : "arjun", 
    "countries" : {
        "country" : [
            {
                "name" : "russia pakistan"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "india iraq"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want a document which has only `russia`. Ideally it should be the one highest scored, but instead I get something like `"Found 3 hits."`

```
Document<stored,indexed,tokenized<id:586b723b4b9a835db416fa26> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS<name:test> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS<countries:{ "country" : [ { "name" : "russia"} , { "name" : "USA china"}]}> stored,indexed,tokenized<country:russia> stored,indexed,tokenized<country:USA china>>**0.12874341**

Document<stored,indexed,tokenized<id:586b73f24b9a835fefb10ca5> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS<name:nitika jain> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS<countries:{ "country" : [ { "name" : "russia and denmrk"} , { "name" : "USA china"}]}> stored,indexed,tokenized<country:russia and denmrk> stored,indexed,tokenized<country:USA china>>**0.12874341**

Document<stored,indexed,tokenized<id:586b744f4b9a835fefb10ca7> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS<name:arjun> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS<countries:{ "country" : [ { "name" : "russia pakistan"} , { "name" : "india iraq"}]}> stored,indexed,tokenized<country:russia pakistan> stored,indexed,tokenized<country:india iraq>>**0.12874341**
```

All 3 results are equally scored. How can I get the document with only `russia` to be highest scored?

Answer (score 0):

In Phrase queries, the slop is zero by default, requiring exact matches. that means that if you modify your query in this way:

```
query query = new PhraseQuery.Builder()
                        .add(new Term("country","russia"))
                        .build();
```

you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: actually its working if while indexing i keep the feild as a stringFeild instead of text feild and make a normal query and not a phrase query but i need the feild to be TextFeild .